# Using, protecting, and understanding ZF database sessions and how to retrieve them?

Tags: database, zend-framework, session, frameworks

What is the correct way to use Database/Cookie sessions? I'm storing my sessions in the database right now. I however don't know the correct and safe way to use it. Can anyone explain to me the logic behind it and how to use it? Here are questions to help post an answer.

Once I store the session in the database, how do I recall it once the person closes their browser?

What are some ways to make the session/cookie safe, as in not being vulnerable to cross site attacks and stuff?

Any recommendations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `Zend_Session` seems to have a pretty good discussion of this topic you can find it at [Zend_Session Global Session Managment](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html)